# in Windows command line: How to know the path of a command?

Tags: java, command-line, which

I have some program in many places (it is the `java` command)..
I am starting this command from CMD. the problem is, I need to know exactly the path of the `java` command being run..

(If you know unix, I need a command such as `which` ).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [Which for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/which.htm) help?

Answer (score 9):

There is no need to install **`WHICH`**, as Windows has a native command that does the same things, called [**`WHERE`**](http://ss64.com/nt/where.html).

It is a native command on Vista onwards, but can be added from the Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit on earlier versions of Windows.

Comment: You can make an which alias to where if you want.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an exact equivalent of "Unix's which" in Windows, but that does not mean there is no solution ;) Check out the following link:

[**Which for Windows**](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/which.php)

Answer (score 1):

Because time ago I could not found an adequate alternative of "which" command for windows, I implemented a simple replacement in python featuring also partial matches of command names:

https://gist.github.com/667891

Hope you find it useful :)